# Including .cpp file in the header file for a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I do know that template class's definition and implementation should be on the same header file. But I was taught a bit differently at school.

I'll have the template class's definition in the header file, and at the end of the header file, I'll do #include "MyFile.cpp", which contains the implementation of the templated class.

Is this bad programming practice?

Comment: Nope, it's very common for implementations to do this although they tend to give a different suffix to make it clear it's not meant to be compiled separately like "tcc" in the case of GCC.

Comment: It's just a convention issue.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys!

Comment: You just have to make sure that whatever build system you're using doesn't automatically try to compile the .cpp file. And include it within the include guards.

Comment: It's a pointless slight of hand in my view. A cpp (or tcc) file included in a header is a header for all intents and purposes. Might as well do the straightforward thing and put all the code in a single file.

Comment: @john This may clutter readability of the header a lot. That's the reason why it's externed.

Answer (score 5):

> *"Is this bad programming practice?"*

In general not and it's a very common technique. But the problem is the `.cpp` file extension, that would affect many IDEs and build systems to consider it as a regular source file. More commonly used extensions are `.tcc`, `.tpc`.

Comment: +1 `.tcc`; There are so many ways software can mess up already, no sense using `.cpp` to confuse your build system when `.tcc` is common.

Comment: I've also seen `.tpp` and `.inl`, the latter being used because `inline` functions deserve the same treatment.

Comment: @Morwenn There's not really a common convention, and I have seen a lot of different styles. The important point is to make it distinct from what is used by the build system to find regular c++ source files.