# WordInfo Class implementation error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, class, implementation, lnk2019

I'm implementing a WordInfo class that holds a word and the lines that the words appear in. But some reason I'm getting a LNK2019 Error when trying to build (I incrementally rebuild as I go to make sure it works).

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include "List.h" 
#include "List.cpp"
namespace cs20 
{
    class WordInfo 
    {
        public:
            WordInfo();
            WordInfo(std::string w);
            WordInfo(std::string w, int l, bool duplicates = false);
            bool addLine(int lineNo);
            bool removeLine(int lineNo);
            std::string getWord() const;
            int getCount() const;
            bool operator > (const WordInfo & ws) const; 
            bool operator < (const WordInfo & ws) const;
            bool operator == (const WordInfo & ws) const;
        private:
            std::string word;
            List<int> lines; 
            bool allowDuplicateLines;
    };
}


#include "WordInfo.h"

namespace cs20 
{
    WordInfo::WordInfo()
    {
    }

    WordInfo::WordInfo(std::string w)
        :word(w)
    {
    }

    WordInfo::WordInfo(std::string w, int l, bool duplicates)
        : word(w), allowDuplicateLines(duplicates), lines()
    {
        //lines.insert(l); 
    }

    bool WordInfo::addLine(int lineNo)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool WordInfo::removeLine(int lineNo)
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::string WordInfo::getWord() const
    {
        return word;
    }

    int WordInfo::getCount() const
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bool WordInfo::operator>(const WordInfo & ws) const
    {
        return word > ws.word;
    }

    bool WordInfo::operator<(const WordInfo & ws) const
    {
        return word < ws.word;
    }

    bool WordInfo::operator==(const WordInfo & ws) const
    {
        return word == ws.word;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
**1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cs20::ListNode<int>::ListNode<int>(int const &,class cs20::ListNode<int> *)" (??0?$ListNode@H@cs20@@QAE@ABHPAV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cs20::List<int>::List<int>(void)" (??0?$List@H@cs20@@QAE@XZ)**

And if I uncomment lines.insert(l), I'll get more errors:

1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cs20::ListNode<int>::ListNode<int>(int const &,class cs20::ListNode<int> *)" (??0?$ListNode@H@cs20@@QAE@ABHPAV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cs20::List<int>::List<int>(void)" (??0?$List@H@cs20@@QAE@XZ)


1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall cs20::ListNode<int>::nextIsNull(void)const " (?nextIsNull@?$ListNode@H@cs20@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall cs20::List<int>::isEmpty(void)const " (?isEmpty@?$List@H@cs20@@QBE_NXZ)


1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int const & __thiscall cs20::ListNode<int>::getElement(void)const " (?getElement@?$ListNode@H@cs20@@QBEABHXZ) referenced in function "public: class cs20::ListIterator<int> __thiscall cs20::List<int>::findPrevious(int const &)const " (?findPrevious@?$List@H@cs20@@QBE?AV?$ListIterator@H@2@ABH@Z)


1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cs20::ListNode<int> * __thiscall cs20::ListNode<int>::getNext(void)const " (?getNext@?$ListNode@H@cs20@@QBEPAV12@XZ) referenced in function "public: class cs20::ListIterator<int> __thiscall cs20::List<int>::findPrevious(int const &)const " (?findPrevious@?$List@H@cs20@@QBE?AV?$ListIterator@H@2@ABH@Z)


1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cs20::ListNode<int>::setNext(class cs20::ListNode<int> *)" (?setNext@?$ListNode@H@cs20@@QAEXPAV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cs20::List<int>::insert(int const &)" (?insert@?$List@H@cs20@@QAEXABH@Z)


1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall cs20::ListIterator<int>::isValid(void)const " (?isValid@?$ListIterator@H@cs20@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cs20::List<int>::remove(int const &)" (?remove@?$List@H@cs20@@QAEXABH@Z)


1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int const & __thiscall cs20::ListIterator<int>::retrieve(void)const " (?retrieve@?$ListIterator@H@cs20@@QBEABHXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cs20::List<int>::makeEmpty(void)" (?makeEmpty@?$List@H@cs20@@QAEXXZ)


1>WordInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __thiscall cs20::ListIterator<int>::ListIterator<int>(class cs20::ListNode<int> *)" (??0?$ListIterator@H@cs20@@AAE@PAV?$ListNode@H@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: class cs20::ListIterator<int> __thiscall cs20::List<int>::findPrevious(int const &)const " (?findPrevious@?$List@H@cs20@@QBE?AV?$ListIterator@H@2@ABH@Z)
```

Comment: Don't include `List.cpp`.

Comment: If `List.cpp` are implementations of template code in `List.h`, include it at the bottom of `List.h`, inside the include guards. And make sure your build system doesn't try to compile it.

Comment: @juanchopanza The file should probably renamed also to `List.tcc`

Comment: @NO_NAME I took out List.cpp but there's still 3 errors

Comment: @juanchopanza I did that after taking out List.cpp, but now there's more LNK2019 errors

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ does that stand for template? I never seen that in my books

Comment: @Crowning see here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004171/including-cpp-file-in-the-header-file-for-a-template-class/32004313#32004313

Comment: It hard to tell what is wrong with this project. These errors are generated by linker, so they refer to the structure of the whole project rather than this particular file. Read [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.